# How to return a value of another column within groupby+apply

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                             'obj': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                             'x0': np.repeat(np.random.rand(3), 3), 
                             'y0': np.repeat(np.random.rand(3), 3), 
                             'x': np.random.rand(9), 
                             'y': np.random.rand(9)})


   group  obj        x0        y0         x         y
0      1    1  0.577952  0.936173  0.681409  0.905242
1      1    2  0.577952  0.936173  0.995970  0.284488
2      1    3  0.577952  0.936173  0.436973  0.163712
3      2    1  0.802995  0.264205  0.586934  0.292848
4      2    2  0.802995  0.264205  0.204437  0.022746
5      2    3  0.802995  0.264205  0.626687  0.000793
6      3    1  0.343862  0.847310  0.966428  0.496161
7      3    2  0.343862  0.847310  0.465727  0.512349
8      3    3  0.343862  0.847310  0.069815  0.689743
```

I'd like to aggregate this DataFrame to the one that would look like below:

```
   group        x0        y0  closest
0      1  0.577952  0.936173        3
1      2  0.802995  0.264205        1
2      3  0.343862  0.847310        1
```

where `closest` is a value of `obj` which is the closest to `(x0, y0)` in each `group`. However, I have trouble with using `aggregate` function to calculate the distance using columns. The farthest I get is:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: np.sqrt((x['x0'] - x['x']) ** 2 + (x['y0'] - x['y']) ** 2).argmin())
```

where I calculate index of closest `obj`, but I don't know how to return the value of `obj`. I have tried `lambda x: x.iloc[ np.sqrt((x['x0'] - x['x']) ** 2 + (x['y0'] - x['y']) ** 2).argmin(), 'obj']`, but it results in error. Therefore my question are:

- How can I return a value of `obj` and not an index?
- What is the object that I obtain from groupby + apply? it doesn't seem to be a DataFrame, since I can't use `.iloc` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) with helper column created for improved performance:

```
df['new'] = np.sqrt((df['x0'] - df['x']) ** 2 + (df['y0'] - df['y']) ** 2)

df = df.loc[df.groupby('group')['new'].idxmin()]
print (df)
   group  obj        x0        y0         x         y       new
0      1    1  0.577952  0.936173  0.681409  0.905242  0.107982
3      2    1  0.802995  0.264205  0.586934  0.292848  0.217951
8      3    3  0.343862  0.847310  0.069815  0.689743  0.316116
```

Your solution return same values of `obj`:

```
def f(x):
    x = df.iloc[np.sqrt((x['x0'] - x['x']) ** 2 + (x['y0'] - x['y']) ** 2).argmin()]
    return x

df = df.groupby('group').apply(f)
print (df)
       group  obj        x0        y0         x         y
group                                                    
1        1.0  1.0  0.577952  0.936173  0.681409  0.905242
2        2.0  1.0  0.802995  0.264205  0.586934  0.292848
3        3.0  3.0  0.343862  0.847310  0.069815  0.689743
```

But there is warning:

> The current behaviour of 'Series.argmin' is deprecated, use 'idxmin' instead.
>   The behavior of 'argmin' will be corrected to return the positional minimum in the future. For now, use 'series.values.argmin' or 'np.argmin(np.array(values))' to get the position of the minimum row.

Comment: I like the first approach and its efficiency. But how can I handle the case when all values of `new` column within the groups are `NaN` and in the result `NaN` is passed to `df.loc` resulting in `KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported`?

Comment: @jakes  1.idea is using reindex instead loc, but I guess idxmin with nan return nan, so reindex creates new row filled nans. I think main question is what is expected output of nans? Because if first row of group then should be trick replace nans to maximal value float of python or some big int. So it return first value if all nans per group but also avoiding if only some nans per groups this values cannot be used (because then has to exist at least one less number).2. idea is simply drop all nans rows per new column by df.dropna(subset=['new']).Not tested,because offline, on phone only.

Comment: I would expect `new` column to have `NaN` value if `idxmin()` results in `NaN`. I'm afraid `dropna` won't work like that as it'll throw out the whole row.

Comment: I went with your first suggestion though, i.e. `df['new'] = np.sqrt((df['x0'] - df['x']) ** 2 + (df['y0'] - df['y']) ** 2).fillna(9999);  
df = df.loc[df.groupby('group')['new'].idxmin()]; df['new'].replace(9999, np.nan)` and it worked fine!